# Genymotion 2.8.1 issues with ADB

Tags: android, macos, adb, genymotion

I'm using genymotion 2.8.1 and android studio 2.3.1 and my OS is OSX 10.12.3. I have my Android SDK setup in ~/Library/Android/sdk. I've pointed genymotion to the same and my Android studio local.properties also to the same.

But when I start up genymotion device and try to run adb I just get an error saying the socket "5037" is already in use. When I run `ps -ef | grep adb` I get the following

```
  505  2532     1   0  2:08PM ??         0:00.70 adb -L tcp:5037 fork-server server --reply-fd 5
```

So I'm assuming this process was started by genymotion when trying to connect to the device. But when I run `adb devices` from the same path (I checked what path the adb process was running was from using the activity monitor) it throws this error

```
List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now at tcp:5037 *
error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: Address already in use
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

So can someone clarify what is happening here ? Is this a issue with this version of Genymotion and should I try downgrading it ?

Comment: Have you tried `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server`?

Comment: Yes. It throws the same error saying that daemon is not running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally after lot of mix and match I found out that the issue was with the latest ADB version. Download this older version of the platform tools for mac - [platform-tools_r25.0.3](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r25.0.3-darwin.zip)

Then goto where your sdk folder is and replace the platform-tools with the extracted platform-tools from the above mentioned package. Hope this helps others facing the same issue